# Rendering Pug/Jade Mixins in specific order

Tags: pug

Is there any way to make jade/pug wait for something to execute before rendering the next part of the page?

Trying to realize a page-index/navigation, automatically generated from the content-sections:

### Example

```
var arr = []

mixin section(content)
 - arr.push(content.title)
 h1= content.title
 p= content.text

mixin index()
  ul
    each item in arr
      li= item
```

-

```
+index() // arr/index is empty at this time

+section({foobarz})
+section({foobarz})
+section({foobarz})
+section({foobarz})
...

+index() // arr/index works perfectly
```

Placing the index in front of the sections results in an empty arr/section since the sections aren't executed yet. After the section mixins it works fine, unfortunately the index makes no sense at the end of the page.

Already considerd a dirty setTimeout to wait for the sections to be compiled. But that doesn't seem to be able to render actual markup:

```
mixin index()
    - 
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(arr) // works fine, full array is looged
        ul // doesn't render anything at all
          each item in arr
             li= item 
      },500)
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem! To my knowledge, this is not possible with the process you propose, as Pug files (and files in many other markup languages) are usually evaluated sequentially / top-to-bottom, not in parallel.

One solution I can think of is to split the data-definition and data-use steps: First, in the beginning of the file, you define the complete array of objects, and then you later iterate on that array with `+index` and `+section` commands. Another solution might be to define that array somewhere else (e.g. in a JSON/YAML file that you could load in the script that calls the compiler on these files). You could then pass the loaded array on to this template through context variables.

Either solution is not ideal, but they do make the problem solvable.